# Problema en compilación con gcc - error: unknown type name ‘stack_t’

Tags: c, compilador

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
// Para glibc
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 199309L

#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <ucontext.h>

volatile int FromHandler = 0;
ucontext_t RootContext;

void alarmHandler( int );
void usr1Handler( int, siginfo_t *, void * );
void ethernal( void );

int main( void ) {
  struct sigaction sa = { };
  sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  sa.sa_sigaction = &usr1Handler;

  // Colocamos los manejadores, y de paso el context raiz.
  signal( SIGALRM, alarmHandler );
  sigaction( SIGUSR1, &sa, NULL );

  if( !FromHandler ) {
    printf( "Entramos en la función eterna ...\n" );
    alarm( 5 );
    ethernal( );
  } else {
    // Es 'supuestamente' imposible llegar aquí ...
    printf( "¡ Hemos salido de la función eterna !\n" );
  }

  return 0;
}

void ethernal( void ) {
  while( 1 );
}

void alarmHandler( int sig ) {
  (void)sig;

  FromHandler = 1;
  setcontext( &RootContext );
}

void usr1Handler( int signo, siginfo_t *info, void *ctx ) {
  const ucontext_t *context = (ucontext_t *)ctx;

  if( signo == SIGUSR1 ) {
    // Establecemos el contexto raiz.
    memcpy( &RootContext, context, sizeof( ucontext_t ) );
  } else {
    // Se nos llamó mediante SIGALRM.
    FromHandler = 1;
    setcontext( &RootContext );
  }
}
```

Al intentar compilar, obtengo el siguiente error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/ucontext.h:26:0
                 from test.c:8:
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ucontext.h:137:5: error: unknown type name ‘stack_t’
     stack_t uc_stack;
```

Una de las funciones que utilizo, `sigaction( ... )` indica en su manual que

```
Feature Test Macro Requirements for glibc (see feature_test_macros(7)):
   sigaction(): _POSIX_C_SOURCE
   siginfo_t: _POSIX_C_SOURCE >= 199309L
```

Cosa que hago en la *primera* línea del archivo, antes de nada.

He revisado **todas** las demás funciones de mi código, y no he encontrado mas avisos de `Feature Test Macro Requirements`

La pregunta: ¿porqué muestra ese error?

**EDITO**

Lo he intentado con `clang`, con idénticos resultados.

Comment: Te recomiendo, en vez de definir la macro en el archivo fuente, lo hagas en la linea de comandos al compilar, así la macro está habilitada desde el principio y no la evalua al momento de compilar el `main.c` que traes, por defecto es el último que se compila *(hasta donde tengo entendido)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#define _BSD_SOURCE
```

Con la instrucción anterior se debería solucionar (ponerlo antes de los `#include`).

La documentación de `feature_test_macros(7)` se detalla [aquí](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) (en inglés) y básicamente viene a decir que para versiones de glibc posteriores a 2.12 tienes que definir ciertas macros para activar determinadas características.

Hay otras formas de activar ciertos elementos, por ejemplo jugar con los valores de otras macros. La documentación es ciertamente extensa.

Comment: _BSD_SOURCE me muestra un aviso, y sugiere cambiarlo por _DEFAULT_SOURCE. Con este último, si. ¿ podria considerarse un fallo de la glibc ? Las páginas de manual de las funciones implicadas solo indican lo que comento en la pregunta.

Comment: No creo que sea un fallo de glibc. Yo creo que el tema es que son diferentes versiones de la librería.

Comment: Compilar, compila. Funcionar ... es otro tema xD

Comment: @Trauma Cuando esas funciones vienen desactivadas por defecto es por algo... El hecho de obligarte a declarar las macros es una forma de que seas consciente de que eso lo estás haciendo bajo tu propia responsabilidad

Comment: Muchas de las funciones en `<ucontext.h>` están declaradas como **deprecated** en las últimas POSIX. La que pretendo usar, `setcontext( )` es de las pocas que se salvan. Tengo entendido que es mas por temas de usar C moderno que por otra cosa, pero claro, de la teoría a la práctica ...